# How to correct an Access Denied using Ampps?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, ampps

I started using Ampps tonight for the first time on my Windows machine. I was not aware when I began that the default password when using Ampps for the MySQL database was "mysql". I kept getting connection errors and then I went into localhost/phpmyadmin and changed the root users password from in there and got an Access Denied error that I have been unable to resolve or find documentation to resolve.

To be clear, I have not even gotten past the part of installing WordPress yet when this occurred. So there is no code to paste and I am using Windows 7.

Please help.

Comment: If you did not know that the password for `root` was `mysql` then you will not have changed anything with phpMyAdmin

Comment: I changed the password for root user in phpmyadmin, after which I started getting access denied. There was no password there when I made the change. I mention the "mysql" default because had I known that I would have configured wp.config.php accordingly.

Comment: When you're trying to connect through phpMyAdmin, do you get a login prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the inconvenient.
The best way to have AMPPS access denied fix is manually.
Follow the steps and make sure things are in place accordingly.

1. Download and install AMPPS.
2. Once installed, open the AMPPS on desktop. If the MySQL button didn't run,
3. Click on MySQL SETTINGS and then, click on CONFIGURATION to open on notepad.
4. Stroll down a little bit and sure PASSWORD, PORT are set to:

(a) password = mysql

(b) port = 3306 (for MySQL button to run, change 3306 to any 4 digit port number of your choice. and wherever you see 3306 should be equally be change to same number of your choice along the settings path when through down).

(C) socket = "{$path}/mysql/mysql.sock"

Please don't include a,b,c in brackets. This are my own of listing the steps for easy to follow. After change port number, save and close the notepad. After saving settings, close and  Restart AMPPS.

5. If MySQL button runs, click on HOME  at the top and when it open on the window address as localhost/ampps/
   Click on PHPMYADMIN to try to access login section.
   When the LOGIN section opens, if access denied or when you are trying to login failed (with username: root and default password: mysql).
6. Goto the root folder of your AMPPS where it's saved in C:\ drive. That's, C:\Ampps
   and open the exact folders after it like this:
   C:\Ampps\phymyadmin\config.inc.php

Right click and open config.inc.php on text editor and made changes to:

$cfg['servers'][$i]['port'] = 'insert your 4 digit number here';

Remove the 'insert your 4 digit  number here' . This are my own statement. My way of explaining it for easy to understand.
Example:
$cfg['servers'][$i]['port'] = '3390';
Replace it with number of your choice you first use in settings.

7.
$cfg['servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

Config is changed to cookie. Save it.

8. Goto C:\Ampps\data\my.conf
   Open my.conf on test editor and make sure the default password is : mysql

Save it.

9. Goto C:\Ampps\phpMyAdmin\config.sample.inc.php
   Click and open config.sample.inc.php on test editor.
   $cfg['servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

   Make it's set to cookie. Save it.
10. $cfg['servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

    It's your choice to decide.
    If you want to allow the use of password, set it to:  $cfg['servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

If you don't want to allow the use of password, set it to:  $cfg['servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Save your settings and close it.
After all the steps are followed, restart your AMPPS.
Click on HOME  and click on phyMyAdmin to either login with your default username: root and default password: mysql depending on what you choose in [AllowNoPassword] = TRUE or FALSE to have access to  phpMyAdmin index.
Thanks.